# Blazor wasm website not updating after publish

Tags: .net-5, blazor-webassembly

I am new to blazor and working on my first app.

I have publish my wasm app and api written in .net 5 to a hosting server, but after publishing the changes and opening the site, the changes don't show. How can I force the new version to the client every time I publish to the server?

Notes: the app is not PWA

Comment: Sounds very similar to this issue https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20408

Comment: Thanks for the comment, have not figured it out yet but I think it pointed me in the right direction!

Comment: Try using a private window, this will confirm cache issue, which is most probably what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

1- Check if you're uploading all files including _framework folder.

2- Check if your CDN is not caching the old version. It's possible that you update a file, however because the filename is not changed, the CDN won't notice that the content has changed.

3- If you add PWA, then you can simply use [this package](https://github.com/jsakamoto/Toolbelt.Blazor.PWA.Updater) (or even do it yourself if you can) to notify about the new version.